# json RequireJS plugins + jasmine

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jasmine

I'am using [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/)  for testing JavaScript code.
The javascript code is made of module which are loaded using requireJs.
When I load json file using [json requirejs-plugins](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins)  which requires `text! plugin` I cannot see any output on the web browser.
The strange thing is also I don't get any javascript error.

Here's my code (1).

Any ideas?

P.S.:
Not sure but maybe the problem is about time latency.
If I get the file from the local (`time latency = 6ms`) it works.
If I get the file (with the same content of local) from a remote server (`time latency = 170 ms`) it display an empty page.
Any idea how can I fix this problem?

---

(1)

```
/*global define, window*/
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var specUrl = './';
    define([
        'jasmine',
        'jasmineHtml',
        'jasmineJquery',
        'json!json_data', // if I comment this line is ok, 
                          // otherwise I get empty page with no error
        specUrl + 'models/user.spec'
    ], function (jasmine) {
        var initialize = function () {
            // some code
        };

        return {
            initialize: initialize
        };
    });
}());
```

---

I did read the documentation about [Asynchronous specs](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs) but it is not clear how can I fix the issue, yet. Any ideas?
I did post a very simple code: (1) which works, (2) which does not works because, maybe, getting json_data from the server requires about 250ms.

(1)

```
    define([
        'appJasmine',
//        'json!json_data',
    ], function (app) {
        app.initialize(); // it display data on browser
    });
```

---

(2)

```
    define([
        'appJasmine',
        'json!json_data',
    ], function (app) {
        app.initialize(); // it does not display data on browser
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run execJasmine before all modules will be ready you will get empty page.
So you should post your code about execJasmine call.
For example, if you are running this code:

```
        window.onload = function () {
            if (currentWindowOnload) {
                currentWindowOnload();
            }
            execJasmine();
        };
```

you will get an empty page.

If you run this one, it should work.

```
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (currentWindowOnload) {
                currentWindowOnload();
            }
            execJasmine();
        }, 0)
```

Comment: The problems with timeouts is they are not reliable with async calls. This will fail if at some point there are more modules or you are dealing with higher than usual latency.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look inside the jasmine documentation for asynchronous calls, most likely won will need to wait for the property to be present before you can run your spec.

https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs

According to your updated question and reading through the jQuery plugin doc you provided, the problem is clear:

```
/**
 * Your App code
 */
var myTestObj = {};
define([
    // some stuff
], function () {
    // will be called when everything is ready
    myTestObj.loaded = true;
});


/**
 * Jasmine spec
 */

describe("My suite", function() {

    it("should run some test", function() {
        // waitsFor is called periodically and will only execute
        // the following run statement when it returns true
        // waiting will be aborted after 10 seconds in this example
        waitsFor(function() {
            return myTestObj.loaded;
        }, "Async modules to be loaded", 10000);

        runs(function() {
            expect(myTestObj.loaded).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });

});
```

This is a very basic example, but you should get the principle. WaitsFor checks for a condition periodically and you can use run statements to execute after waiting is finished. You can use the run statements to wrap describe, it or expect calls.

Comment: thanks for your response but actually it is not clear how can I fix the issue, yet. I did update my answer, please read it. thanks.